# Raspberry Pi 4 Python not finding installed libraries

Tags: python-3, opencv

I trying to connect an OpenCV OAK-D to an R Pi 4B.

I've downloaded & installed all the requirements & installed the `depthai` library using `pip`

To check its there,

```
pip3 list | grep depthai
depthai 2.19.0.0
```

Check that the OAK-D is being seen,

```
lsusb | grep 03e7
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 03e7:2485 Intel Movidius MyriadX
```

Yes that's the one.

Run the camera example,

```
sudo python3 rgb_camera_control.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file path", line 39 in <module>
    import depthai as dai
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'depthai'
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

EDIT::SOLVED As pointed out by goldilocks in the comments, the problem was that I hadn't installed the library with `sudo`. Once done it all started working.

Comment: I think the usual issue here is that you installed the libraries as a normal user, which installs to your home directory (not the system libs), then you are trying to run it as root (`sudo`), which does not use libs in some user's home, it uses the system wide ones.

Comment: I though there would be a decent duplicate of this if I was correct, but looking around this one is probably the best, because the title is generic (not just about "depthai"), and you've presented the problem in a clear and concise way -- so I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you've used `pip` as the `pi` (or some other normal) user, which installs the libraries to that user's home directory.  Then you execute a script via `sudo`, which runs it as `root`, aka. the superuser, which uses the system libraries.

Likely then you want to install using `sudo pip`.  However, beware when doing this to check first that what you want isn't available from the `apt` repository, otherwise there is a possibility that at some future point it may get installed as a dependency of something else, using `apt`'s dependency resolution and not `pip`'s.  This could lead to the modules ending up in an inconsistent state.

In this case, though, I think that is not an issue.